# Xcode profile data warnings

Tags: ios, xcode, optimization

I have no idea how Xcode tests work. I clicked "Generate Optimization Profile" (under "Product" -> "Perform Action>"). I see no profile, and I now have 3 warnings that appear when I try to build:

First one:

```
profile data may be out of date: of 6 functions, 0 have no data and 1 has mismatched data that will be ignored
```

Second one:

```
profile data may be out of date: of 85 functions, 4 have no data and 1 has mismatched data that will be ignored
```

Third one:

```
profile data may be out of date: of 220 functions, 81 have no data and 0 have mismatched data that will be ignored
```

Can someone translate these warnings into English? :p

I know generating another optimization profile will suppress them temporarily, but what do they mean?

Comment: it is maybe related to [this](http://mozeryansky.com/2014/12/apple-llvm-6-0-warning-profile-data-may-be-out-of-date/)

Comment: @0yeoj can you add your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is maybe related to this [Apple LLVM 6.0 Warning](https://mozeryansky.com/apple-llvm-6-0-warning-profile-data-may-be-out-of-date/) (**updated link**)

> **How To Fix**: [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/xcode_profile_guided_optimization/pgo-tasks/pgo-tasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014459-CH2-SW5),
>   Apple described how to use the Optimization Profile and how to enable
>   it. I don’t want to use the profile I generated and corrupted, so I’m
>   going to properly delete it and disable it. You can always regenerate
>   the profile to fix this problem.

1. Delete the group folder ‘OptimizationProfiles’ in your project
2. Set the ‘Use Optimization Profile’ for the release to ‘No’
3. Build again